# CSS to change color from grey to #330000

Tags: html, css

I grabbed this from W3 schools and I am trying to apply a colour to the class - so I created the style section and tried to apply color but its not working. I know this is linked to an outside style sheet, so maybe that's overriding what I want to do.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .label label-default {
      background color: #330000;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>



  <h1><span class="label label-default">Survey</span>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 problems

1. The selector is not good. `<span class="label label-default">`. If you want to select this, you need to write `.label.label-default`

You should use a `multi class selector` , read here -> [multi class selector](https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/#article-header-id-2)

Read more about [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

2. The `background color` style is not correct either. You need to write `background-color`

Read more here -> [background-color](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp)

3. `h1` tag has to be closed with `</h1>`

Read more here -> [HTML Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/Html/html_elements.asp)

*My own question* -> Why use a `span` inside the `h1` if you don't split the content or is there some other reason ? For eg `<h1><span class="font-light">Light</span>Not Light</h1>`.

If you have no special reason to use span inside the `h1`, you should add the `classes` directly on the `h1`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  
  .label.label-default {
  background-color:#330000;
  }
  
  </style>
  
</head>
<body> 
 


  <h1><span class="label label-default">Survey</span></h1>
  


</body>
</html>
```

*I know this is linked to an outside style sheet, so maybe that's overriding what I want to do* -> the linked stylesheet is a bootstrap stylesheet. To check if that overwrites your own custom css, inspect your code in developers console and see if your styles are cut out. Then they are overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are missing `.` in your class selector, next you have to remove the space between selectors since they are applied to the same element. You also have to add `-`to `background-color` property. Finally close the `h1` tag and you're done:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  
  .label.label-default {
  background-color:#330000;
  }
  
  </style>
  
</head>
<body> 
 


<h1><span class="label label-default">Survey</span></h1>
  


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css is incorrect, first of all its is "background-color" not "background color"

and second if you want to apply css for same div classes then you should not give space for class name like ".label .label-default"

you have to write class names without spaces like this ".label.label-default"

try this

```
  <style>
  .label.label-default {
      background-color:#330000;
  }
  </style>
```

instead of this

```
  <style>
  .label .label-default {
      background color:#330000;
  }
  </style>
```