# Apply HTML & CSS to Moodle HTML Source Editor

Tags: html, css, moodle, moodle-mobile

I am really basic at HTML/CSS but with the help from this website I managed to get the following working. The colour looks right, so its all working. 
But when I put this in the HTML Source Editor in Moodle the colour disappears, so I know that its a HTML editor and the colour is contained in style as CSS. So i guess I need to link to a style sheet to give me that colour, but I have no idea how to do that. Or maybe I am wrong about that, and something else could be done.

I already checked W3 Schools, and its most likely I just don't have the jargon yet to properly look for the answer to this problem, so a google search when you simply don't have the vocab for what exactly I am looking for is difficult. 
Please if you can help that's great, but I also want to better know what it is I should be looking at, as I am only doing this for Moodle, any places you can point me to where I can find or see how HTML/CSS works with Moodle so I can learn about it so I can slowly build up my own knowledge. I greatly appreciate this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  
  .label.label-default {
  background-color:#009999;
  
  
  </style>
  
</head>
<body> 
 


  <h1><span class="label label-default">Survey</span></h1>
  


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe this will help ? https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=341721 .Plus you asked one question yesterday ( regarding somehow this problem ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50922376/css-to-change-color-from-grey-to-330000 and you didn't accept an answer. Please do so

Answer (score 0):

I will answer to you , first you put style css in same file of html ,so remove the whole link of style . then in style write like this

Answer (score 0):

I advise to you use Adobe Dreamweaver program , I hope my answer solve your problem.